# Android Gingerbread: NFC support - Receive Only?

Tags: android, nfc

Just looking through the newly released [Gingerbread documents](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html) and I see they've added some support for Near Field Communication (as expected).

However, it looks to me like its receive only (you can receive NFC communications and messages but you can't send them). Is that everyone's interpretation? Haven't had a chance to do a deep dive here, but that's what it looked like to me. Just 3 classes added and I don't see a send() method anywhere.

So receive only is Ok, but then that would leave us with cell,wi-fi,bluetooth if we need to communicate back. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

In Android 2.3, I don't think so. I agree that it looks read-only, in terms of the API and the sample code they supply.

However, indications are that the Nexus S NFC hardware supports read and write, so perhaps additional APIs are coming in future versions of Android.

In the interim, think of NFC tags as playing a role akin to QR codes.

Comment: For more info, check this video from the Nexus S page: http://goo.gl/knPwf It mentions near the end that it is read-only but it seems they have the capability to send in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Gingerbread release there is write support for tags, and for limited P2P functionality. With enableForegroundNdefPush() you can send NDEF messages to the other device.

Answer (score 0):

The [Android 2.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html#api) docs does state that the functionality has read only capability, but makes no mention of transmision. Send capabilities seem to be implicitly unavailable with the current release.

> "Android 2.3 includes an NFC stack and
>   framework API that lets developers
>   read NDEF tags..."

Answer (score 0):

> Android 2.3.3 provides improved and extended support for NFC, to allow applications to interact with more types of tags in new ways.
>
> A new, comprehensive set of APIs give applications read and write access to a wider range of standard tag technologies, including:
>
> - NFC-A (ISO 14443-3A)
> - NFC-B (ISO 14443-3B)
> - NFC-F (JIS 6319-4)
> - NFC-V (ISO 15693)
> - ISO-DEP (ISO 14443-4)
> - Mifare Classic
> - Mifare Ultralight
> - NFC Forum NDEF tags

See the [API Overview](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html#api) page for more information.